# Excel: Concatenating cells & text using IF statements

Tags: excel, concatenation

I'm trying to combine several cells of data. My problem is in placing spaces between data and, more importantly NOT putting a space when there's no data so I don't get double spaces. Here's a sample:

```
=TRIM(M12)&IF(N12<>M12;"-"&TRIM(N12);"")&" "&TRIM(G12)&" "&TRIM(H12)&IF(LEN(I12>0);" "&TRIM(I12)&" ")&TRIM(J12)
```

The data is start year (M), end year (N), make (G), model (H), body style (I), driveline (J).

For some the values in start year and end year are the same.

```
&IF(N12<>M12;"-"&TRIM(N12);"")
```

This works perfectly. If the end year is the same as the start year it does not add a - or space after.

For many rows there is no value in body style.

```
&IF(LEN(I12>0);" "&TRIM(I12)&" ")
```

This will print the body style if it's present but it always adds a double space if there is no value in body style.

When I change that reference to:

```
 &IF(LEN(I12>0);"-"&TRIM(I12)&"+")
```

both the - and + print regardless of what's in I12

I've tried many variations. None work, some throw errors. Probably obviously, I do not know what I'm doing in Excel but I'm thinking there must be a better way of checking the cell I12? I tried >1 with no luck but I'm not sure what to check besides the length of the data within.

Comment: Why not just `TRIM` the entire output?

Comment: your `)` are in the wrong place and do not forget the `""` in the False: `&IF(LEN(I12)>0;"-"&TRIM(I12)&"+";"")`

Answer (score 0):

The `TRIM` function not only removes leading and trailing spaces, but also reduces any internal multiple space sequences to a single space.  By wrapping the whole formula in `TRIM(..)` you can ignore the possibility of creating double spaces.

Regarding

> When I change that reference to:
>
> `&IF(LEN(I12>0);"-"&TRIM(I12)&"+")`
> both the `-` and `+` print regardless of what's in `I12`

This suggests that `I12` actually has one or more spaces.  Fix that by using `LEN(TRIM(I12))>0`

Or better, just go ahead and concatenate `I12` and let `TRIM` clean up the spaces.

<sub>Note: I'm assuming the `IF(LEN(I12>0);"-"&TRIM(I12)&"+")` version was just to test that bit of code, so haven't delt with adding `-` and `+`.</sub>

So, your whole formula can become

```
=TRIM(M17&IF(M17<>N17;"-"&TRIM(N17);"")&" "&G17&" "&H17&" "&I17&" "&J17)
```

If you have a version of Excel that supports `TEXTJOIN` then you can use

```
=TRIM(M16&IF(M16<>N16,"-"&TRIM(N16),"")&" "&TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,G16:J16))
```